# Detecting a cycle in a directed graph via an adjacency list implementation and a recursive DFS

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

Here's my attempt. I iterate through each vertex in the graph and do a DFS to see if I reach back on a vertex I already visited in this vertex's iteration. It seems to work but I am not satisfied with how I short-circuit my code when it found a cycle using if clauses, could not think of a better way to do that.

```
public boolean isCyclic(Map<T, List<T>> adjacencyList) {

    for (T node: adjacencyList.keySet()) {
        Set<T> visited = new HashSet<>();
        visited.add(node);
        if (isCyclic(visited, node) == true)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean isCyclic(Set<T> visited, T node) {
    boolean retval;
    for (T connectedNode: map.get(node)) {
        if (visited.contains(connectedNode)) {
            // We've reached back to a vertex, i.e. a back-edge
            return true;
        } else {
            visited.add(connectedNode);
            if (isCyclic(visited, connectedNode) == true)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find another way to do it, but I will give you some tips on the current implementation.

### Always add curly braces to `loop` & `if`

In my opinion, it's a bad practice to have a block of code not surrounded by curly braces; I saw so many bugs in my career related to that, if you forget to add the braces when adding code, you break the logic / semantic of the code.

### Simplify the boolean conditions.

In both of the method, you can simplify the boolean validations.

#### Equivalence

`isCyclic(visited, node) == true` can be `isCyclic(visited, node)`

**Before**

```java
if (isCyclic(visited, node) == true) {
   return true;
}
```

**After**

```java
if (isCyclic(visited, node)) {
   return true;
}
```

#### Code reduction

In the second method, instead of using the `java.util.Set#contains` method, you can check the returned boolean of the `java.util.Set#add` directly; this will allow you to remove an instruction.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#add(E)):

```
Returns:
true if this set did not already contain the specified element
```

**Basic example**

```java
Set<Character> set = new java.util.HashSet<>(Set.of('A', 'B', 'C'));
System.out.println(set.add('A')); // false
System.out.println(set.add('D')); // true
```

This will add the element, if not already present and return `true` if it was not present.

**Before**

```java
if (visited.contains(connectedNode)) {
   // We've reached back to a vertex, i.e. a back-edge
   return true;
} else {
   visited.add(connectedNode);
   if (isCyclic(visited, connectedNode)) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

**After**

```java
if (!visited.add(connectedNode)) {
   // We've reached back to a vertex, i.e. a back-edge
   return true;
} else {
   if (isCyclic(visited, connectedNode)) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

---

In the second method, you can remove the `retval` variable, since it does nothing.

Comment: Upvoted just for the brackets with for/if part. i introduced so many errors when adding a second statement and forgetting to add the brackets and I swore never to write an if without brackets again.

Comment: Thank you for the handy advice, yes I got lazy about the curlies around the if condition :)